# Cant get users from my db, undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass "rails tutorial"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Im following the RoR tutorial by Michael Hartl and im at chapter 9.3 "Showing all users" so far everything has worked great but now I am getting an undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass when trying to retrieve my users from the SQlite database. Here is my controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

.
.
.

def index
@users = User.all
end
end

    and my index.html.erb

<ul class="users">

<% @users.each do |user| %>
<li>
<%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
<%= link_to user.name, user %>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

With this code i get the error undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

And when i change it to

```
<ul class="users">
<% if @users %>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<li>
<%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
<%= link_to user.name, user %>
</li>
<% end %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

I can render the view but displaying 0 users although i have users in my db. I have created some manually and also used the 'faker' gem to spawn some. In the rails console typing User.all returns an array with 100 users. I cant seem to find the missing link here. Im also using the SQlite Database browser app to check out my User model where i also have 100 Users.
I have worked a lot with this and cant seem to figure things out.

Here is my User.rb aswell

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
has_secure_password

before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
before_save :create_remember_token

validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence:   true,
format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

private

def create_remember_token
self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
end
```

Comment: Your next step in learning should be the learning of debugging. Very simply you can debug using 2 ways. Rails.logger.debug(some_var) or use using the "debugger" gem. Ensure you have the debugger gem in your Gemfile, then write "debugger" just after you fetch all your users in the controller. Hit the page with your browser and move back to your terminal where the server is running, hopefully you'll be at a prompt where you can inspect the @users instance variable's values.

Comment: Can you comment/remove the signed_in_user filter just to check if it has something to do with the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's curious that `User.all` is returning `nil` instead of an empty array `[]`. Try the following:

1. make sure you've run any pending migrations

   ```
   rake db:migrate
   ```
2. If the previous step didn't run any migrations, try wiping your database and starting again, just for good measure:

   ```
   rake db:drop
   rake db:create db:migrate db:seed
   ```
3. go into a rails console, and make sure `User.all` is behaving correctly

   ```
   rails c
   >> User.all
     User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
   => []
   >> exit
   ```
4. If this all works, try putting some debug statements into your controller (using pry or the ruby debugger is optimal, but even some `puts` statements will suffice here) to examine the value of `@users`
5. Next, you'll want to either add some seeds to the database (edit db/seeds.rb and run `rake db:seed`) or use scaffolded forms to add some users.

Comment: Ok so the solution was quite simple after the help from Ben Taitelbaum, and also required myself to learn about a few different debbuging methods which is great. I used the Rails.logger.debug to fully understand what was going on and caught my def show method being called before my def index and canceling it out. I simply moved def index over def show in my controller and voila. Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

another really helpful debugging tool is the pry gem.  you can find it on github.

it will stop program execution at the point in your code where you put the command:

binding.pry

and allow you to have a rails consol- access variables, call methods... whatever.

it's a great handy tool for debugging.